# What do you mean by "Developers use the returned Future object to track progress of the transmission."

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was going through javaee documentation where in I came across this.
It is the method present in Interface RemoteEndpoint.Async.
sendBinary-->

```
Future<Void> sendBinary(ByteBuffer data)
```

Initiates the asynchronous transmission of a binary message. This method returns before the message is transmitted. ***Developers use the returned Future object to track progress of the transmission.*** The Future's get() method returns null upon successful completion. Errors in transmission are wrapped in the ExecutionException thrown when querying the Future object.
Parameters:
data - the data being sent.
Returns:
the Future object representing the send operation.

I wanted to know what the author meant by progress.Suppose I am transferring a file.Will it show me the percentage of file transferred?

Answer (score 2):

This notion refers to the equivalent notion of 'Promise' in Javascript. In this context of an async call, 'progress' represents the success or failure of the operation, not it's percentage.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.